# How to apply Time-Series Decomposition to custom dataset

Tags: python, pandas, time-series, statsmodels

##### Goal: Trying to apply time-series decomposition on my own CSV dataset to find trend, seasonality and noise of the LeftHipAngle column

I would like to apply time-series decomposition on a CSV (found [here](https://github.com/lucaphen/EEE4022S/blob/main/subject_31_angle_joints.csv)) using pandas dataframe, but I keep getting frequency errors. My process is as follows:

##### Step 1: Load in the CSV to Pandas Dataframe

```
from statsmodels.tsa.seasonal import seasonal_decompose
from dateutil.parser import parse

# Decomposition of a Time Series
import pandas as pd
url = 'https://raw.githubusercontent.com/lucaphen/EEE4022S/main/subject_31_angle_joints.csv'

df = pd.read_csv(url, parse_dates=['Time'], index_col='Time')
# dataset has duplicated time values passed 460 rows, which cause errors,
# ...so I limit the value to 420
df = df[:420] 
print(df.head())
print(type(df))
```

Result can be seen [here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/j6pwD.png)

##### Step 2: Use Statsmodel to access seasonal_decomposition function

```
# Use Statsmodel to decompose time-series
result_mul = seasonal_decompose(df['LeftHipAngle'], model='multiplicative', extrapolate_trend='freq')
```

Here, I get an error:

> ValueError: freq L not understood. Please report if you think this is in error.

##### Attempted Diagnosis

I think the problem is related to the frequency of the Time-Series being in milliseconds (ie. 'L') but when I add `df = df.asfreq('L')`  under `df = df[:420]`  in the first step's code, I get this error ([here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/eKxPI.png)).

I would appreciate any help, I'm trying to incorporate custom .csv files for Time-Series Analysis.

Answer (score 0):

I played around with this a little bit and changed the index to 'L' as you did and got errors that function doesn't handle missing data. So I reindexed like so:

```
date_index2 = pd.date_range(start=df.index.min(), end=df.index.max(), freq='L')
df = df.reindex(date_index2).fillna(0)
```

which expanded the rows greatly.

Then I got this error:

```
ValueError: Multiplicative seasonality is not appropriate for zero and negative values
```

Then I tried not filling Nan with 0 and got this error

```
ValueError: This function does not handle missing values
```

I think the real issue is that you have a dataset that isn't matched well with the function you are trying to use. Perhaps another package or function can approximate what you are trying to do.